# Update Using Subquery to Identify Changed Records

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

Need to update selected records in MySQL table A where the value of a checksum field is not equal. I have been attempting subqueries with no success. I would appreciate help with syntax or suggestion if a better way is known. The "Checksum" field in the two tables was created using MD5 and concatenating selected columns.

I receive the error "You can't specify target table 'migrate' for update in FROM clause "when I run the following query.

```
UPDATE migrate 
INNER JOIN people_holding 
ON migrate.Identification = people_holding.Identification
SET
  migrate.Title = people_holding.Title, 
  migrate.CompanyId = people_holding.CompanyId, 
  migrate.CompanyName = people_holding.CompanyName, 
  migrate.Processed = "Changed"
WHERE 
  migrate.Identification IN (SELECT
  people_holding.Identification
FROM people_holding
INNER JOIN migrate
  ON people_holding.Identification = migrate.Identification
WHERE people_holding.Checksum <> migrate.Checksum);
```

Comment: You just need to change the WHERE to people_holding.Checksum <> migrate.Checksum

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I was making it more difficult and your direction was exactly what I needed.